Is it possible to show rows and seconds when running mysql with `-e`?
When running any query in mysql in interactive mode, the output includes a line such as the following:
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

However, if I run any query with mysql -e "select * from foo;", then I am missing this line.
Is it possible to get this line even when I am running with -e?

Yes, by using -v -v options. That is, -v twice.
Once is not enough:
mysql -v -e "select version()"   
--------------
select version()
--------------

+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.39    |
+-----------+

It's gotta be at least twice:
mysql -v -v -e "select version()"
--------------
select version()
--------------

+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.39    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Bye

You can see that the verbose option enables some other output besides the result size line. As far as I know, you can't get the result size without the other verbose output.

yes, but you need the json output you can get those meta data
JSON format is being used for the output


To help integrate MySQL Shell with external tools, you can use the --json option to control JSON wrapping for all MySQL Shell output when you start MySQL Shell from the command line. The --json option only takes effect for the MySQL Shell session for which it is specified.

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-json-wrapping.html
You would get at the end somthing like
"executionTime": "0.0067 sec",
"affectedRowCount": 0,
"affectedItemsCount": 0,
"warningCount": 0,
"warningsCount": 0,
"warnings": [],
"info": "",
"autoIncrementValue": 0


There is a basic profiling tool in the MySQL:
mysql -e "set profiling=1; select * from foo; show profile; set profiling=0;"

More detailed info from manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/show-profile.html
